# How to split and align LHS and RHS independently?

Tags: align

I want to obtain the following result in which each step of the expanding is split, the left hand side and right hand side are aligned with different vertical lines independently.

The purpose is to explain that the red expressions can be omitted.

[image]

My attempt is as follows. I don't know what environment should I use here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[a6paper,hmargin=5mm,bottom=13mm,top=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\parindent=0pt\relax

\begin{document}
\textbf{Question}:\\
Expand $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$.

\textbf{Answer}:
\begin{multline*}
(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\\
 = (x-1) (x-2) (x^2 -4x -3x +12)\\
{\color{red}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}\\
= (x-1) (x-2) (x^2 -7x +12)\\
{\color{red}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}\\
= (x-1) (x^3 -7x^2 +12x -2x^2 +14x -24)\\
{\color{red}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}\\
= (x-1) (x^3 -9x^2 +26x -24)\\
{\color{red}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}\\
= x^4 -9x^3 +26x^2 -24x -x^3 +9x^2 -26x +24 \\
{\color{red}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}\\
= x^4 -10x^3 +35x^2 -50x  +24 
\end{multline*}
\newpage

Simplified version:
\begin{multline*}
(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\\
\begin{aligned}
&= (x-1) (x-2) (x^2 -4x -3x +12)\\
&= (x-1) (x-2) (x^2 -7x +12)\\
&= (x-1) (x^3 -7x^2 +12x -2x^2 +14x -24)\\
&= (x-1) (x^3 -9x^2 +26x -24)\\
&= x^4 -9x^3 +26x^2 -24x -x^3 +9x^2 -26x +24 \\
&= x^4 -10x^3 +35x^2 -50x  +24 
\end{aligned}
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `align*` in both cases:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,hmargin=5mm,bottom=13mm,top=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Question}:\\
Expand $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$.

\textbf{Answer}:
\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft[1] (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\\
&= (x-1) (x-2) (x^2 -4x -3x +12)\\
\MoveEqLeft[1] \textcolor{red}{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}\\
&= (x-1) (x-2) (x^2 -7x +12)\\
\MoveEqLeft[1] \textcolor{red}{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}\\
&= (x-1) (x^3 -7x^2 +12x -2x^2 +14x -24)\\
\MoveEqLeft[1] \textcolor{red}{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}\\
&= (x-1) (x^3 -9x^2 +26x -24)\\
\MoveEqLeft[1] \textcolor{red}{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}\\
&= x^4 -9x^3 +26x^2 -24x -x^3 +9x^2 -26x +24 \\
\MoveEqLeft[1] \textcolor{red}{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}\\
&= x^4 -10x^3 +35x^2 -50x  +24 
\end{align*}

Simplified version:
\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft[1] (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\\
&= (x-1) (x-2) (x^2 -4x -3x +12)\\
&= (x-1) (x-2) (x^2 -7x +12)\\
&= (x-1) (x^3 -7x^2 +12x -2x^2 +14x -24)\\
&= (x-1) (x^3 -9x^2 +26x -24)\\
&= x^4 -9x^3 +26x^2 -24x -x^3 +9x^2 -26x +24 \\
&= x^4 -10x^3 +35x^2 -50x  +24 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See if the following is what you like to have:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[a6paper,hmargin=5mm,bottom=13mm,top=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\parindent=0pt\relax

\begin{document}
\textbf{Question}:\\
Expand $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$.

\textbf{Answer}:
\begin{align*}
&(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\\
&\quad = (x-1) (x-2) (x^2 -4x -3x +12)\\
&{\color{red}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}\\
&\quad = (x-1) (x-2) (x^2 -7x +12)\\
&{\color{red}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}\\
&\quad = (x-1) (x^3 -7x^2 +12x -2x^2 +14x -24)\\
&{\color{red}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}\\
&\quad = (x-1) (x^3 -9x^2 +26x -24)\\
&{\color{red}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}\\
&\quad = x^4 -9x^3 +26x^2 -24x -x^3 +9x^2 -26x +24 \\
&{\color{red}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}\\
&\quad = x^4 -10x^3 +35x^2 -50x  +24
\end{align*}
\newpage

Simplified version:
\begin{align*}
    \MoveEqLeft
(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\\
    &= (x-1) (x-2) (x^2 -4x -3x +12)\\
    &= (x-1) (x-2) (x^2 -7x +12)\\
    &= (x-1) (x^3 -7x^2 +12x -2x^2 +14x -24)\\
    &= (x-1) (x^3 -9x^2 +26x -24)\\
    &= x^4 -9x^3 +26x^2 -24x -x^3 +9x^2 -26x +24 \\
    &= x^4 -10x^3 +35x^2 -50x  +24
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]